# Get a collection using user uid to generate Firestore reference

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to set a firestore collection in a service to later return an observable of its documents

```
@Injectable()
export class ContactService {

  private contactCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
  private contactDocument: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private afs: AngularFirestore
  ) {
    this.authService.user
      .subscribe(user => this.contactCollection = this.afs.collection(`directories/${user.uid}/contacts`));
  }

  getContacts(){
    return this.contactCollection.valueChanges()
  }
```

this works fine if i navigate to the route that displays the component that consume the service but if i visit directly the route or refresh the page the contactCollection is undefined.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: joining the question